# inherit decorator/annonation in angular 2 ver 2.x.x

Tags: angular

I was using custom decorators before **RC5** version of angular 2 but now it is not possible(giving errors). is there any idea to resolve this.

```
export function CustomComponent(annotation: any) {
  return function (target: Function) {
    var parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;

    var parentAnnotations = Reflect.getMetadata('annotations', parentTarget);

    var parentAnnotation = parentAnnotations[0];
    Object.keys(parentAnnotation).forEach(key => {
      if (isPresent(parentAnnotation[key])) {
        if (!isPresent(annotation[key])) {
          annotation[key] = parentAnnotation[key];
        }
      }
    });

    var metadata = new ComponentMetadata(annotation);

    Reflect.defineMetadata('annotations', [ metadata ], target);
  };
};
```

Using above as

```
@CustomComponent({
  selector: 'sub'
})
export class SubComponent extends AbstractComponent {
}
```

Tutorial was at https://medium.com/@ttemplier/angular2-decorators-and-class-inheritance-905921dbd1b7#.yqki96a5y
above code was working fine before RC5 version of Angular2 (**before NgModule**)

Error Stack ->

```
Error: (SystemJS) parentAnnotations is undefined
    CustomComponent/<@http://localhost:3000/app/customCompo.js:8:13
    DecorateConstructor@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:531:29
    decorate@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:115:20
    __decorate<@http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:4:84
    AppComponent<@http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:16:20
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:12:21
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:1:2
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:13:23
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:2
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:3:20
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:2
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:229:17
    Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:24
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:509:52
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:262:21
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:28
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:405:25
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:336:25

    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
Stack trace:
(SystemJS) parentAnnotations is undefined
    CustomComponent/<@http://localhost:3000/app/customCompo.js:8:13
    DecorateConstructor@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:531:29
    decorate@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js:115:20
    __decorate<@http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:4:84
    AppComponent<@http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:16:20
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:12:21
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js:1:2
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:13:23
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:2
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:3:20
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:2
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:229:17
    Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:24
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:509:52
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:262:21
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:28
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:405:25
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:336:25

    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.component.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

Comment: Angular 2.3.0 was released yesterday, which supports component inheritance.

Comment: I tried with Angular 2.3.0 but no luck @Tony

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works the old way you used to do it, but since Angular 2.3.0
They work out of the box as they should, following oop principles. Example below:

```
import { SomeService } from './../services/someservice';
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

// decorators work, and are overwritten by the child.
@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <div> {{getText()}}</div>
  `,
})
// can use abstract class, with abstract methods, which require
// the child class to implement them.
@extendedCustomDecorator('Some custom stuff  for parent')
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  // decorators work
  @Input() text: string;

  private t: string = 'this is the parent';

  // dependency injection works.
  // 
  constructor(protected ss: SomeService) { }

  // lifetime hooks work, and are called
  // need to remember to explicitly call them if you override them
  // from the child with super.ngOnInit()
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('parent', this.text);

  }
  // methods can be private, protected etc.
  // and follow normal oop principles.
  getText(): string {
    return `${this.t} ${this.text}`;
  }

  getText2(): string {
    return ' this is second text from parent';
  }

}


@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <div>{{getText()}}</div>
  `
  })
@extendedCustomDecorator('Some custom stuff for child')
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() text: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    // super.ngOnInit() works if you want both to be called
    // console.log('child', this.text, this.ss.someSharedValue);
  }

  getText(): string {
    return `this is child component some text from parent: ${super.getText()}, ${this.getText2()}`;
  }

}

export function extendedCustomDecorator(value: string) {
  return function (
    target: Function // The class the decorator
  ) {
    let parentTarget = Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype).constructor;
    console.log('extendedCustomDecorator', value, target);
  };
}
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: This works fine but I need to extend annonation/decorator